# How to output a Vector into a JTextArea in a JFrame?

Tags: java, vector, textarea

Let's just say i have a Vector of Strings, and I want to output them to a JTextArea. What methods should I use?

I was thinking of using a for loop with:

```
Vector temp = new Vector();
String temp = list.getText(i) + '\n';
textArea.setText(temp);
```

Which I know does not work. I heard of append() doing something related, but wasn't sure what to do. Any tips?

Comment: Uh oh, two variables in scope with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you're close. I think what you meant was...

```
Vector<String> list;
...
String tmp = "";
for( int i = 0 ; i < list.size(); i++ )
{
   tmp = tmp + list.get(i) + "\n"; 
}
textArea.setText( tmp );
```

And in regard to your other comment, yes, whenever running a loop that appends a string value, you're going to want to use `StringBuffer` instead of string...

```
Vector<String> list;
...
StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer();
for( int i = 0 ; i < list.size(); i++ )
{
    tmp.append( list.get(i) + "\n");
}
textArea.setText( tmp.toString() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `Vector` is a synchronized container. What this means is that it's thread safe. Unless you are planning to access it using multiple threads, there's little point and you're better off just using an `ArrayList`.

Secondly, unless you're using a really ancient version of Java, you'll want to make sure you're using a parametrised container, ie:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

To check for methods on a JTextArea, the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) is your friend.

You'll also need to loop over your container to append all its elements as well.